# Parallel computing over a function from linked library in C

Tags: c, macos, parallel-processing, intel, lapack

I am new to parallel computing and searching for options and tricks.

My present problem is to find 2<sup>32</sup> independent linear equations of type B = AX; where dimensions of A[8x8], B[8x1] and X[8x1]; A is a Dense matrix.

I am using CLAPACK - zgelss function for this in a sequential order on a Intel core 7i processor, 4 core, 8 thread and a Mac machine.

Further it seems my matrix size is small enough to use internal optimization.

I want apply a parallelism over this the loop:

```
for (n = 0; n < 2^32; n++)
{...}
```

I want to ask what are my options to do that.

A few people suggested use [OpenMP](http://openmp.org/), but after reading about OpenMP I found out that we cannot apply OpenMP directives to the part of code which is precompiled.

If we do so, it works but it might not be safe because you can not privatize the temporary variables inside the precompiled functions.
{Please comment right/wrong/other}

So I want to ask how it can be done, if it is possible.
Some tricks.... anything...

Comment: Have you thought about using the GPU to do this?

Comment: yep I have thought of that -- but I was not able to find any open source library for calculating SVD... on gpu. or a C/C++ source code which can handle complex data. NR for provide a c code and trick for computing it for complex data.. but that is not good enough... Maybe if you know you can suggest some library  that I can use on Mac OsX and ATI Radeon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true that unless you know the library you want to call is thread-safe, you can't just thread calls to it.  However, as of Lapack 3.3, all [lapack calls are threadsafe](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lapack-3.3.0.html) (although if you're using a different underlying BLAS package to power the lapack routines,  you'll have to make sure they too are threadsafe).  Clapack is just a thin layer of wrappers around lapack calls; they ought to be threadsafe [***Edit***: This is wrong, as pointed out by janneb below; Clapack is a direct automatic C translation of an older version of Lapack, so it's likely not threadsafe] , but if you can't find anything about it in the documentation to be sure, it's straightforward enough (if a little fiddly) to call the Fortran routines directly.

The alternative would be to make the various function calls in different processes, rather than threads.   That takes a bit more doing, but it's easy enough.  The canonical way would be using MPI - which has certain advantages but may be somethig of overkill in this case.

Comment: CLAPACK is actually LAPACK which has been translated to C (with the f2c tool). Latest version is 3.2.1, BTW. However, it says on the homepage it's thread-safe.

Comment: That sounds like a terrible idea on all sorts of levels.  Better then to just use the C interface to LAPACK, http://www.netlib.org/lapack/#_standard_c_language_apis_for_lapack .

Comment: Don't blame me, I'm not the originator of that travesty.. :) To be honest though, IIRC CLAPACK dates back to the days when no free Fortran compilers were available. Also, since current LAPACK uses some F90 features, I suspect this means the end of the road for CLAPACK, since f2c supports only F77. As you note, the way forward is the new official C bindings, "lapacke".

Comment: Thanks a lot Jonathan and Janneb.
I am using Mac Ox 10.6 -- Snow Leopard.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jonathan and Janneb.
I am using Mac Ox 10.6 -- Snow Leopard.
It comes with its own BLAS and LAPCK library
How can I make Sure which version I am using ..

Answer (score 0):

with the help of information provided by Jonathan and janneb I am able to  parallelize over the function zgelss successfully, using openMP.

I used LAPACK 3.3 and created my own FORTRAN to C interface.